# How do I set up an Angular project to develop a web with landing pages and the Angular app inside some path?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-routing

I want to create a web whose URLs will be like the following:

- example.com, example.com/about, example.com/contact, example.com/landing... are static pages.
- example.com/app is the root of my Angular app. With routing to things like example.com/app/login, example.com/app/profile and the like.
- example.com/admin is the root of another Angular module. It also has routing for the different views.

I know that I can build the Angular modules separately and place the build results in the respective directories next to my static pages and serve everything with a node server. But how do I modify the template that `ng new` (the Angular CLI) creates to be able to use `ng serve` to serve the whole web (static pages and Angular modules) with automatic reloads on code changes.

Comment: Have you looked at the proxy settings: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md. Note that [tag:angular] is already specific to Angular, not [tag:angularjs].

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the stories in the Angular CLI repo. I don't see how your link could provide me with a solution to my question, though. I don't want to have several servers running. Just the one from `ng serve` serving my static pages and my angular app with two modules.

Comment: I guess I can use the `npm start` script to run a different server like they mention [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/disk-serve.md), copy the static pages to **dist/** and use `ng build -- watch` to build each Angular app (they can't be 2 modules of the same app in this case I think) to **dist/app/** and **dist/admin/**. But I kinda hope I can find a better solution.